# Web Server for Progressive web apps

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am a beginner to developing a Progressive Web Apps, as i have used Chrome Web Server initially to host my progressive web application.But i don't know how to host my PWA app on other web server.
Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

1. Get a GitHub account, install GitHub software, and commit some code to your repo
2. Get a free Heroku account, and install Heroku CLI on your computer.
3. Point your Heroku account, in its configuration, to your Git repo's master branch
4. If your app consists of static files, follow the following instructions (Heroku only hosts non-static sites):

Add a file called composer.json to the root directory by running:

```
touch composer.json
```

Add a file called index.php to the root directory by running:

```
touch index.php
```

Rename the homepage (e.g. index.html) to home.html

In index.php, add the following line:

```
<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>
```

In composer.json, add the following line:

```
{}
```

From a command line, CD into your project's root directory. Run the following command:

```
git push heroku master
```

5. You should now have a staging server on Heroku, with https enabled. Whenever you commit code to your master branch and sync it with GitHub.com, there will automatically be a deployment behind the scenes from your GitHub repository to your Heroku hosting account. Boom! You have all the ingredients you need to stage a successful PWA application. Production hosting is up to you, maybe try DigitalOcean to start with.